# Update Column in table using Select, Inner Join and Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called: `Claim`, where I've already moved data from another table called `Damage`. However, today I needed to add a column in `Claim` called `ClaimStatusID`. And to give values to `ClaimStatusID` I need to to it based on another column called `DamageApprovedStatusID`, which exists in yet another table called `DamageErrand`. `Damage` and `DamageErrand` has relation through a crosstable called `DamageErrandCrossDamage`. In that crosstable `DamageErrandID` and `DamageID` exists. Here, I've commented more information:

```
-- Claim has column ID which has the same ID as the table Damage
-- DamageErrand has DamageApprovedStatus ID which need to be inserted
-- to ClaimStatusID, where the ID's need to be correct.
-- Table Damage and Table DamageErrand has a cross table:
-- DamageErrandCrossDamage, where both of their ID's are stored
-- Claim.ID should therefore be the same as DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID
-- Since Claim.ID has the same ID as Damage.ID
-- IF DamageApprovedStatus = -1, SET ClaimStatusID = 0
-- IF DamageApprovedStatus = 0, SET ClaimStatusID = 4
-- IF DamageApprovedStatus = 1, SET ClaimStatusID = 2
```

And here's a SQL query I created for selecting and using `Case When` to give the correct statuses:

```
SELECT Claim.ID as claimid, DamageErrandID as damageerrandeid,
CASE --
WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = -1 THEN 0
WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 0 THEN 4
WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 1 THEN 2
ELSE '-'
END AS DamageApprovedStatusID,
DamageApprovedStatusID
FROM
DamageErrand
INNER JOIN DamageErrandCrossDamage ON DamageErrand.ID = 
DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageErrandID
INNER JOIN Claim ON DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID = Claim.ID
WHERE Claim.ID = DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID
```

I do believe this is correct, with the ID's matching and everything. But how can I actually update the `table Claim` with this? I know `insert` won't work since I have columns that does not allow null in `Claim` table. I tried doing something similar to:

```
--UPDATE Claim
--SET ClaimStatusID = 
--(SELECT DamageApprovedStatusID FROM
--DamageErrand 
--INNER JOIN DamageErrandCrossDamage ON DamageErrand.ID = 
-- DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageErrandID
--INNER JOIN Claim ON DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID = Claim.ID
--WHERE Claim.ID = DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID)
```

But obviously this won't work either. Really thankful for any help!
Btw: I'm using SQL-server for this.

Comment: it will be easier for all to understand your question better if you can provide some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
UPDATE Claim
    SET ClaimStatusID = alias.DamageApprovedStatusID
FROM (
    SELECT DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID, 
        CASE 
            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = -1 THEN 0
            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 0 THEN 4
            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 1 THEN 2
        ELSE '-'
        END AS DamageApprovedStatusID
    FROM DamageErrand 
        INNER JOIN DamageErrandCrossDamage ON DamageErrand.ID = DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageErrandID
) alias
WHERE Claim.ID = alias.DamageID
```

I guess it could be rewritten like this too:

```
UPDATE Claim
    SET ClaimStatusID = CASE 
                            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = -1 THEN 0
                            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 0 THEN 4
                            WHEN DamageErrand.DamageApprovedStatusID = 1 THEN 2
                            ELSE '-' 
                        END
FROM DamageErrand
    INNER JOIN DamageErrandCrossDamage ON DamageErrand.ID = DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageErrandID
    INNER JOIN Claim ON DamageErrandCrossDamage.DamageID = Claim.ID
```

Comment: Do you mean to say "Claim" instead of "alias"?

Comment: Which line are you referring to? `alias` is as subquery that is then joined to `Claim` by `Claim.ID = alias.DamageID`

Comment: Ahh yes, the obscure `update` without `join`. Nevermind.